# Copy ComboBox from a Word Document to another Word Document with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2003

I have a combo box (combo1) in a word document and I would like to copy it to another word document. (end game will be looping through 100's of docs).

I can't for the life of me work out how to select and/or copy the combo box, although its easy enough to do outside of vba.

So far I've tried turning it into a bookmark, seems to select ok, but won't copy.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(combo1_bm).Select
Selection.Copy
```

I thought it would be able to done as an inline shape (as that is how they are added?), however again the selection appears to work, but the Copy doesn't.

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(combo1).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Any ideas on what I can try next?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt with bookmark was quite good. You just need to extend your code a bit:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("combo1_bm").Range.Copy
....
Selection.Paste        'or different pasting procedure
```

Keep in mind that you don't need to select object before copy it. Just try doing as I show above. Moreover, don't miss quotation marks for names or use bookmark index to work with appropriate one. `Copy method` will copy inside range of the bookmark and keep original bookmark in place, unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, it does work! 

However the bookmark needs to include the entire line + the one above for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
Set ComboBox1Range = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("combo1_bm").Range.Start - 1, _
                             End:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("combo1_bm").Range.End)
ComboBox1Range.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
ComboBox1Range.Copy
```